# Binding textbox inside listbox in windows phone 7 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I have tetbox inside the list box data template. That textbox is editable. How to get the textbox text value in selection changed event. If i tried to find the text using visual tree it returns nothing. Please help

```
ListBoxItem item = this.lstProds.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
PhoneTextBox targetBox = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<PhoneTextBox>(item);
string a = targetBox.Text;

private T FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(DependencyObject parentElement)   where T : DependencyObject
{
        var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parentElement);
        if (count == 0)
            return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parentElement, i);

            if (child != null && child is T)
            {
                return (T)child;
            }
            else
            {
                var result = FindFirstElementInVisualTree<T>(child);
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
}
```

XAML:

```
  <ListBox Name="lstProds" Margin="0,59,0,0" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="Black" SelectionChanged="lstProds_SelectionChanged">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid Height="auto">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="68,63,-58,-13">
             <toolkit:PhoneTextBox Name="txtQuantity" Hint="Quantity"  Width="180" Text="{Binding Quantity}"></toolkit:PhoneTextBox>
            </Border>
           </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
```

Comment: how do you populate the listbox? DataBinding? also please show us the DataTemplate in XAML

Comment: why can't you use the item (collection) you bound the list to?

Comment: I found the solution. thanks @user1859022

Comment: @Rev this isn't your personal blog. If you found the solution please post it as an answer or delete this question... Otherwise how else does this help anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I just add the textbox text property mode as Two way. In the selection changed event get the selected item as a class. var context = (lstProds.SelectedItem as ModelClass);
string a = context.Quantity;

```
  <ListBox Name="lstProds" Margin="0,59,0,0" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="Black" SelectionChanged="lstProds_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
<Grid>
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="91,69,0,9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="145">
                        <toolkit:PhoneTextBox Name="txtQuantity" Hint="Quantity" Width="144" Text="{Binding Quantity,Mode=TwoWay}"></toolkit:PhoneTextBox>
                </Border>    
</Grid>
            </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```